# Programmatically Clear Selection in WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox in WPF whose ItemsSource is set to a list programmatically.  How would I go about clearing the selection in an event handler?  I've tried:

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBox.SelectedItem = null;
comboBox.SelectedValue = null;
comboBox.SelectedValue = "";
```

None of them have any effect.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;` works for me.

Are you doing anything else in your event handler? Are you using databinding?

Comment: No, I'm not using any data binding.  Just double checked.

Comment: Try to do a 'find all references' for comboBox and comment out the code to find the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Is the way to go. I don't know why it doesn't work for you; perhaps an event handler for `SelectedIndexChanged` changes the value?

Answer (score 4):

I found that I needed to also add:

```
comboBox.Text = "";
```

to get the text to clear

Answer (score 1):

I want to clear the `ComboBox` in `DropDownClosed` event of another `ComboBox`. Therefore I used following code inside of first `ComboBox` `DropDownClosed` event

```
private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.comboBox.ItemsSource = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following example I show the way it worked for me, this for a ComboBox from a user control:

Combobox in the usercontrol:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="OFFSE_INI_CMBX" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="100" DropDownClosed="OFFSE_INI_CMBX_DropDownClosed">
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="NV" Content="           NV" ToolTip="Sub Command &#10;Tooltip 1" Height="20" Selected="NV_Selected"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Function that works

```
private void OFFSE_INI_CMBX_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OFFSE_INI_CMBX.SelectedIndex = -1;
        this.OFFSE_INI_CMBX.Text = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1 did not work for me, perhaps because I am using a custom ControlTemplate in a custom ComboBox?? Anyway, reseting the ItemsSource does work. I am calling this from a Behavior.

```
            var items = comboBox.ItemsSource;
            comboBox.ItemsSource = null;
            comboBox.ItemsSource = items;
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you must do this in the selectionchange function

```
private void combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (combobox.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
               combobox.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                string datacombo=(combobox.SelectedValue.ToString());
            }
             

        }
```

after that use it anywhere combobox.SelectedIndex=-1. now I am using another combobox to select on selection change

```
 private void cbocombobox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            combobox.SelectedValue=null;
            combobox.SelectedIndex = -1; 
        }
```

and it worked for me alhamdulillah