# Clear a combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

How do I clear a combobox in WPF?  I have tried this code:

```
 private void btClear1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        txtID.Text = String.Empty;
        this.cbType.SelectedItem = -1;
    }
```

Comment: Clear as in remove all the items, or clear as in clear the selection?

Comment: Instead of selectedItem you could put the SelectedIndex=-1.
Anyway, the answers from @Fred are the most correct ones ;)

Comment: Regarding Fred's comment above, it really depends if the `ComboBox` was filled by just adding a `ComboBoxItem`-either in XAML or dynamically-or if it was filled by binding to the `ItemsSource`. If you use the latter, you cannot do `cbType.Items.Clear()` -- you get: `Operation is not valid while ItemSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.`.  The question really needs to include how the items are populated into the box, in the first place.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627304/programatically-clear-selection-in-wpf-combobox

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic, but I'm curious about your choice of the name `cbType`. To me this implies the value is a type, not a combobox. Is there a WPF or .Net convention I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear the selection set the `SelectedIndex` not the `SelectedItem`

```
cboType.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

You can set the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` as well, but change it to `null` instead of -1 (these point to an object not an integer).

```
cboType.SelectedItem = null;
```

Comment: When I try this I get: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in cbType_SelectionChanged –

Comment: @user2631662 Change your `SelectionChanged` event to check for null before it tries to do things to the combo box selected item

Comment: @user2631662 I suspect in your `SelectionChanged` event you are invoking a method on the `SelectedItem` of the combo box (perhaps `cboType.SelectedItem.ToString()`).  This will throw a null reference if nothing is selected, so just add a condition at the top of that method that says if (cboType.SelectedItem == null) return;

Answer (score 5):

`cbType.SelectedItem = -1` to clear the selection
`cbType.Items.Clear()` to clear all the items

Comment: It really depends if the `ComboBox` was filled by just adding a `ComboBoxItem`-either in XAML or dynamically-or if it was filled by binding to the `ItemsSource`. If you use the latter, you cannot do `cbType.Items.Clear()` -- you get: `Operation is not valid while ItemSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.`.

Answer (score 3):

You can reset the combo box by binding in the XAML page.

For example, in that combobox field in the XAML page:

```
text={Binding viewmodelobject Name.property Name}
```

And then in `ViewModelPage`:

```
viewmodelobject Name.property Name="";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Totally clearing box items**
For Googlers, since the title is misleading, if we were talking clearing the items from the box, I've seen several answers saying to use `cbType.Items.Clear()`.  It depends on how the items were loaded.  You could have hard-coded them into the XAML, added them with a function dynamically at runtime, used a type of databinding and/or loaded them to the `.ItemSource`.  It will work for all but the latter case.

When you are using the `.ItemSource` to load the `ComboBox` via a DataTable's `DefaultView`, for example, you cannot simply do `cbType.Items.Clear()`.  Since the method of populating the dropdown was not included in the question, I submit that for when you set the `.ItemSource`, you must do:

`cbType.ItemsSource = null;`

instead.  Otherwise, if you try `cbType.Items.Clear()` you will get:

```
Operation is not valid while ItemSource is in use. Access and modify 
elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead
```

**Clearing the selected item**
I went back and saw the OP's comment, saying the wish was to clear the selection, not the box.  For that, the other answers stand:

```
cbType.SelectedIndex = -1;  
cbType.Text = "";  // I've found the first line does this for me, as far as appearances, but found other postings saying it's necessary - maybe they were using the property and it wasn't getting cleared, otherwise
```